# How to change "add to cart" text on category view?

Tags: magento2, addtocart

Where can I change the text below?
[image]

Where is the file and where do i need to copy it in my custom theme? Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change add to cart text only in list category page by override template file in your custom theme,

You have to just overrider list.phtml file into your theme,

```
app/design/frontend/{Themepackage}/{yourtheme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

now replace `<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>` with your custom text.

If you want to change text globally for all places in system,
You have to overrider csv file into your theme **i18n** folder. But change using csv also change text in details page.